# Positioning a text field inside a toolbar in Kivy

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to put a textfield inside a toolbar with KivyMD, but the textfield is always directly against the right side of the window. I tried to adjust it with pos_hint, but none of the values I put for the x-coordinates moved it.

```
Screen:
canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: 'assets/bg.png'

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: 'Placeholder'
        elevation: 10
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}

        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: app.menu.open()]]

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: textinput
            icon_left: 'magnify'
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.1 ,'center_y': 0.5, 'right': 0.3}
            size_hint: {.6, .4}
            text_color: 'white'
            hint_text: 'Search'**strong text**
        
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Placeholder'
        color: 'white'
        halign: 'center'
```

[Screenshot of toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ3Zs.png)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert your widgets wherever you want, for this you can specify a position in the widget tree - `add_widget(widget, index)`. I wrote a special `get_widgets` function for your solution, which goes through all the widgets in the class. In the example below, you can place the text field on the left, right, and center. Also examine the `MDToolbar` [source code](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/toolbar/toolbar.kv)

```py
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.weakproxy import WeakProxy

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

KV = """
MDScreen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: 'Placeholder'
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Placeholder'
            color: 'white'
            halign: 'center'
"""


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.search_content = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.add_search('left'))

    @staticmethod
    def get_widgets(root: WeakProxy, class_: str):
        """
        :param root: root widget
        :param class_: which subclass are we looking for
        :return:
        """

        widgets = []
        for widget in root.walk():
            if widget.__class__.__name__ == class_:
                widgets.append(widget)
                print(widget)

        return widgets

    def add_search(self, side: str):
        """
        :param side: left/right/center
        :return:
        """
        box = self.get_widgets(self.root.ids.toolbar, 'MDBoxLayout')[0]  # get root `MDBoxLayout`

        if side == 'left':
            index = 2
        elif side == 'right':
            index = 1
        else:
            index = 0
            self.root.ids.toolbar.ids.label_title.size_hint = None, None
            self.root.ids.toolbar.ids.label_title.opacity = 0
            
            # NOTE: If you remove this `MDLabel`, you cant change `self.theme_cls.material_style`
            # box.remove_widget(self.root.ids.toolbar.ids.label_title)

        boxlayout = MDBoxLayout(padding=[dp(18), dp(0), dp(18), dp(18)])
        self.search_content = MDTextField(icon_left='magnify',
                                          mode='round',
                                          color_mode="custom",
                                          line_color_normal=(1, 0, 1, 1),
                                          line_color_focus=(0, 0, 1, 1),
                                          text_color_focus=self.theme_cls.text_color,
                                          text_color_normal=self.theme_cls.text_color[0:3] + [0.7],
                                          hint_text='Empty field',
                                          )

        boxlayout.add_widget(self.search_content)
        box.add_widget(boxlayout, index)


TestApp().run()
```